# Gradle fails to detect flat dependency

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-project Gradle build (Gradle 4.4).
And I encountered the following issue.

Let's say I have proj1 project with the following build.gradle:

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
   }
}

dependencies {
       compile name: 'lombok-edge'
}
```

proj1 has libs folder with lombok-edge.jar. Project is built successfully.
And I have proj2 that imports proj1:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':proj1')
}
```

When I try to build the whole project proj1 is build but Gradle fails to build proj2 with an error:

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':proj2:compileClasspath'.

  > Could not find :lombok-edge:.
  >   Required by:
  >     project :proj2 > project :proj1

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Gradle supports transitive dependencies, but the way how to get a dependency (and therefor any repository information) is not transitive. Gradle (like Maven) does not care where a dependency comes from, as long as it matches a given signature (group, id, version).

In your example, project 1 defines a Maven dependency and can resolve it via the given `flatDir` repository. Project 2 has dependencies on both project 1 (which is resolved by Gradle) and the transitive Maven dependency. It's the responsibility of project 2 to resolve this dependency and it will check any defined repository, but cannot find it, because the local repository is unkown. This is the reason why the build fails.

If the two projects are related, as they should be if they are both parts of a multi-project build, you should define the local repository in a top-level `build.gradle` file and a `subprojects` closure.